# How to abort a file upload in PrimeNG’s FileUpload component?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, upload, primeng

## 1. Summary

Based on the selected file in PrimeNG's [FileUpload component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload), I want to abort the file upload to the backend server for specific filename patterns. Angular 6.0.7, PrimeNG 6.0.2.

## 2. First approach

### 2.1. HTML part

```
<p-fileUpload #fileUploader name="file" url="{{uploadUrl}}" accept=".jpeg,jpg" 
  auto="auto" mode="basic" chooseLabel=„Upload file“
  (onBeforeUpload)="fileUploadOnBeforeUpload($event, fileUploader)">
</p-fileUpload>
```

### 2.2. TypeScript part

```
fileUploadOnBeforeUpload(event) {
  if (condition) {
    event.xhr.abort();
  }
}
```

### 2.3. Result

The method was called without any errors, but the upload was not canceled.

## 3. Second approach

### 3.1 TypeScript part

```
fileUploadOnBeforeUpload(event, fileUploader: FileUpload) {
  if (condition) {
    for (let file of fileUploader.files) {
      const index = fileUploader.files.indexOf(file);
      fileUploader.remove(event, index);
    }
  }
}
```

### 3.2 Result

The selected files are removed before transfer, which "stops" the upload as intended. But the backend server understandably complains about the empty request in the browser console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`.

## 4. To be solved challenge

How can I abort the file upload in PrimeNG FileUpload component after selection of specific files?

Comment: I am also looking for this solution...

Answer (score 0):

event.xhr.abort();

is for aborting the sent request. So it won't work inside onBeforeUpload or even onBeforeSend. That's what [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) say:

> The XMLHttpRequest.abort() method aborts the request if it has already been sent.

Whatever you do, it will still make a request until you specify customUpload="true" ([docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v6.1.7/#/fileupload))

That's how you can solve it:

1. Specify custom upload

   ```
    <p-fileUpload #fileUpload customUpload = "true" (uploadHandler)="handleUpload($event)">
   ```
2. Handle it in your component.ts

   ```
    handleUpload(event: any) {

    // Do whatever you want here

    if(condition) {
      // Good to go!
      let formData = new FormData();

      for (let file of event.files) {
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
      }

      this.sendFile(formData).toPromise().then((result: any) => {
        if(result.status == 200) { // Success
          // Your code: display a message, update list of files, etc.
        }
      });
    }}
   ```
3. And function to make an actual call

   ```
   sendFile(formData) {
        // http is HttpClient. You can override it and add required authentication headers, etc.
        return this.http.post(this.HierarchyFileUploadUrl, formData);
    }
   ```