# How to abort file upload in Angular PrimeNG FileUpload component?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

Let's suppose my code looks like this:

```
<p-fileUpload ...
  (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload($event)"
  [auto]="true"
>
</p-fileUpload>


fileUploadOnBeforeUpload(event) {
  if (condition) {
    //is it possible to abort the upload here? how?
  }
```

Is there any way of aborting the upload in the onBeforeUpload event handler or otherwise?

Comment: For those who asked the same question I've just posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160913/12492815 You can't abort the request on this step. At least without sophisticated workaround